# How to use Token number in all controller and view pages in laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Actually, I am trying to set global variable. My scenario is when I am login with laravel 5 framework.I don't want to use auth email in any controller and view pages.I want to use Token number which is created by registration page instead of Auth email. so please give some tips or idea for this scenario.

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly this token number is?

Comment: @Jerodev  csrf_token()

Comment: a csrf token is not constant for the user, this can change at any moment.

Comment: @Jerodev  When User register in my application. It Generates one token number that i have stored in db. so when user login in application i will get that token number from db and will set it for global variable so token number will not change.

Comment: So you want the user to login using this token instead of logging in with username and password?

Comment: @Jerodev Nope user will login with username and password. If he will successfully login in my application it will fire one query where it will get token number and save it as global variable in controller. but i try to save it as global variable but it doesn't works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Providing you store the generated token on the user after generating it something like the below in your AppServiceProvider boot method should work:

```php
 <?php
// app/Providers/AppServiceProvider.php

//...

class AppServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{

    //...

    public function boot()
    {
        view()->composer('*', function($view) {

            if(auth()->user()) {

            $user = auth()->user();
            $token = $user->token;

            view()->share("user_token", $token);

            $this->app->singleton('user_token', function () {
                return $token;
            });

        }

        });

    }
}
```

To retrieve the data in a view:

```
{{ $user_token }}
```

in a controller:

```
app('user_token');
```

Comment: how will i get auth in service provider. As per architecture service provider will load first then it will store in to auth variable...!!!

Comment: as far as I am aware by the time you hit the app service provider all of the auth functionality is available

Comment: Undefined variable: user_token (View: C:\wamp64\www\demohotel\resources\views\admin\home.blade.php)

Comment: Apologies, could you try the corrected version?